# ionic capacitor-community/sqlite problems

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor

Ionic 6 app using capacitor-community/sqlite@3.4.2-3.

Creating connection with

`await CapacitorSQLite.createConnection({database:DBNAME,version:DB_VERSION,encrypted:false,mode:"secret"});`

I get the following error:
`"While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length."`

Using 3.4.0 version with same code, the error is:
`"Error: Query: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.getcapacitor.JSArray com.getcapacitor.community.database.sqlite.CapacitorSQLite.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.getcapacitor.JSArray)' on a null object reference"`

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am facing 2 million issues but I think you have put a superfluous curly bracket `{}` in your constructor call and you are calling the object directly.

`const db = await this.sqlite.createConnection(this.dbname, true, 'encryption', 1, false);` :

where `this.sqlite` is initiated in the constructor to a service (angular) with a call to `initializePlugin`

```
    initializePlugin(): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.platform = Capacitor.getPlatform();
            if (this.platform === 'ios' || this.platform === 'android') {
                this.native = true;
            }
            this.sqlite = new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite);
            resolve(true);
        });
    }
```

You may also need the following in your import statement:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import {
    CapacitorSQLite, SQLiteConnection,
    capEchoResult
} from '@capacitor-community/sqlite';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
```

At least, it works for me.